# Convert particular url query in subdomain URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to take all value from "user" parameter of url to subdomain.

i.e, Redirecting below URL

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?user=stackoverflow
```

to

```
http://stackoverflow.example.com/index.php
```

I have my Private Server, and i am ready to configure my `apache.conf` or any required file like `.htaccess` to achieve my goal.

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Have you tried rewriterule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ http://%1.example.com/$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```